# Why chrome dev tools reports font size different than css

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

This can be observed on [MDL site](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#textfields-section) when you set focus on sample3 input, the label font decreases visually:

[image]

Chrome dev tools reports font-size 15.9213px for the label, but when you expand the node the top css entry suggests the font-size 12px:

[image]

What is the explanation for the difference between 15.9213 and 12px? Is it a chrome bug? How to find out what are the actual font properties in that case?

Comment: It shows `16px` based on a 16px rule here: https://puu.sh/t2oQV/251c2f94b7.png

Comment: I have edited the question, I meant the font of the label

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the input you can see a class called `is-focused` is added to the parent div. In the CSS file you'll see these lines:

```
.mdl-textfield--floating-label.is-focused .mdl-textfield__label,.mdl-textfield--floating-label.is-dirty .mdl-textfield__label,.mdl-textfield--floating-label.has-placeholder .mdl-textfield__label {
    color: #3f51b5;
    font-size: 12px;
    top: 4px;
    visibility: visible
}
```

This is what is changing the font size.

Comment: I know, but it does not explain why chrome dev tools shows 15.9213px